# Postgresql giving syntax error for standard SQL OFFSET AND FETCH NEXT in jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I have a native query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column_a OFFSET ? FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY
```

which is translated to

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column_a OFFSET $1 FETCH NEXT $2 ROWS ONLY
```

But PostgreSQL is returning an error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"

If I change the query to:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column_a OFFSET ? LIMIT ?
```

Then there is no error. However, the LIMIT version is not standard SQL, which I want to avoid. Also, both versions run OK in pgAdmin, so it seems it is something related to JDBC?

Any idea why the standard version is not working in JDBC?

Sample code:

```java
public ResultSet testQuery() {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column_a OFFSET ? FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY";
    return jdbcTemplate.execute(query, (PreparedStatement ps) -> {
        ps.setInt(1, 0);
        ps.setInt(2, 10000);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            return rs;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Crucial question: what is your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe PostgreSQL 10.1

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Also spring-jdbc-5.3.22

Comment: I just tested on my v10 instance, and it worked for me (without using Java). The syntax was introduced with PostgreSQL 8.4. Don't use 10.1 for any serious task.

Comment: What is the complete message, as reported in the PostgreSQL server's log file?

Comment: Resolved after upgrading to PostgreSQL 14.5